# MySQL not found command line Windows

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, environment-variables

I am trying to use mysql from the command line.
I am starting the command line using cmd and enter

```
mysql
```

but the command is not recognized.
I added the MySQL Shell and Server to the path variables like this:
[image: Environment Variables]

But it still does not work. Any idea?
Thank you very much.

Comment: which error specifically do you get, have you installed all components with the installer?

Answer (score 0):

So MySQL location is: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin`

open `cmd` as admin and change the directory to the above path

```
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin
```

Then run this command

```
mysql -V
```

This should work
[image]

To set an environment variable follow the steps provided in this link : https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0

Set %MYSQL_PATH% variable value as => `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin`

Then run this command

```
%MYSQL_PATH%\mysql -V
```

Comment: Isn't this what I already did? cd ing into the directory and then executing it works, but I don't know how I can assign the path to a specific variable and then invoke it using %MYSQL_PATH%, when setting the variable I can only input the path.